# PHP - Scanning through folders and including a file if some conditions match

Tags: php

Let's say I have a starting point folder called **scan_inside**. In the folder there are lots of sub-folders and in those sub-folders there might be even more folders with some content.

I would like to scan through all the folders and insert a file **uploadme.xml** if there is an **index.htm** file found in the current destination. How can I achieve this?

Illustration:

Scanning...

- scan_inside:

  - subfolder1

    - style.css
    - logo.png
    - folder

      - homepage.htm
      - index.htm
      - **uploadme.xml** (must be uploaded because an index.htm file was found)
  - subfolder2

    - about.htm
    - logo.png
  - subfolder3

    - index.html
    - **uploadme.xml** (must be uploaded because an index.htm file was found)

Comment: What have you tried yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @stefket I was trying a "scandir" function. But it seems to work with one level folders only. Maybe I need to nest this function somehow. But I believe there is more sophisticated way to do it.

Comment: It is absolute okay to use scandir for this. And yes, you have to use it in a recursive way for the subdirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need recursion, then you can go through all of the files and try to capture the extension. After that, you can add a file to the array.

```
function scanThroughDir($dir) {
    $result = [];
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $filename) {
        if ($filename[0] === '.') continue;
        $filePath = $dir . '/' . $filename;
        if (is_dir($filePath)) {
            foreach (scanThroughDir($filePath) as $childFilename) {
                $fileNameParts = explode('.', $childFilename);

                if(end($fileNameParts) == "xml"){
                    echo end($fileNameParts);
                    $result[] = $childFilename;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $fileNameParts = explode('.', $filename);
            if(end($fileNameParts) == "xml"){
                $result[] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage

```
print_r(scanThroughDir("./"));
```

Comment: It need some work but this function will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code a bit. It seeks for .php files and uploads an uploadme.xml to the same path. Seems to work quite alright but there might be some mistakes, though.

```
    function scanThroughDir($dir) {
        $result = [];
        foreach(scandir($dir) as $filename) {
            if ($filename[0] === '.') continue;
            $filePath = $dir . '/' . $filename;
            if (is_dir($filePath)) {
                foreach (scanThroughDir($filePath) as $childFilename) {
                    $fileNameParts = explode('.', $childFilename);
                    if(end($fileNameParts) == "php"){
                        copy('uploadme.xml', pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/uploadme.xml');
                        $result[] = $childFilename;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $fileNameParts = explode('.', $filename);
                if(end($fileNameParts) == "php"){
                    copy('uploadme.xml', pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/uploadme.xml');
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

scanThroughDir("mainfolder");
```